# Bootstrap input-groups within navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to solve the various issues with Bootstrap input-group placed inside navbar. The formatting http://bootply.com/101777

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <span class="navbar-brand">Game</span>
        </div>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left itg-game">
            <div class="form-group itg-first">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" ng-bind="first.name"></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly ng-model="first.value">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="btn-group itg-action">
                    <button ng-click="swap()" class="btn btn-default itg-action-btn" ng-bind="text"></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href ng-click="resetGame()">Reset game</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group itg-second">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly ng-model="second.value">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" ng-bind="second.name"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group itg-fee">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly ng-model="fee">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">fee</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And the styles:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .itg-game { }
    .itg-game .itg-first, .itg-game .itg-second { width: 12em; }
    .itg-game .itg-fee { width: 8em; }
    .itg-game .itg-action { text-align: center; }
    .itg-game .itg-action .itg-action-btn { width: 15em; }
}
```

There are two issues:

1. The mobile view (less than 768px) is completely rubbish - lines overlaps the borders of the navbar, controls stick to the borders.
2. mid-size version is better but for some reason the third input jumps to the third line.

It looks like the input-groups are not compatible with navbars. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They work fine with the navbar with a minimal amount of fiddling with the css, but you can't have it set up like you have it because the size matters. Input groups are display:table and 100% width, they need a col-. If you had too many links or links with really long names, your navbar would break down crappily.

---

#### DEMO http://jsbin.com/putuki/1/edit

---

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top my-navbar">
    <button class="navbar-toggle visible-xs" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"><!--empty--></span> <span class="icon-bar"><!--empty--></span> <span class="icon-bar"><!--empty--></span></button>

    <div class="container visible-xs">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mynavcollapse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <form>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class='form-control' placeholder="Search: (stuff)" type='text'> <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default">Button</button></span>
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                    </div><!-- /col- -->

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class='form-control' placeholder="Search: (stuff)" type='text'> <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default">Button</button></span>
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                    </div><!-- /col- -->

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class='form-control' placeholder="Search: (stuff)" type='text'> <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default">Button</button></span>
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                    </div><!-- /col- -->

                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class='form-control' placeholder="Search: (stuff)" type='text'> <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default">Button</button></span>
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                    </div><!-- /col- -->
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.my-navbar .row [class*="col-"] {
 margin-top: 10px
}
#mynavcollapse {
clear: both;
padding: 0 0 10px;
background: #eee;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
 .my-navbar .navbar-brand {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
 }
.my-navbar .row {
    margin-left: -.5%;
    margin-right: -.5%;
 }
.my-navbar .row [class*="col-"] {
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: .5%;
    padding-right: .5%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I hoped that the solution with not much custom modifications exists - but it looks like it does not.